# Bootstrap webpage not displaying correctly when browser window is reduced

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently building my first website using Bootstrap - I have made progress but am having issues when it comes to how the contents are positioned when the browser window is made smaller. I have wrapped the contents of the page in a .container-fluid class, but for some reason the footer area (containing contact infomation) moves half-way up the page as soon as the screen-width goes below 990 pixels. What is causing this? Any help much appreciated, thanks.

http://www.jonhowlett.uk

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button class="navbar-toggle" data-target=".navbar-collapse"
            data-toggle="collapse" type="button"><span class=
            "icon-bar"></span> <span class="icon-bar"></span> <span     class=
            "icon-bar"></span></button>
        </div>

        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                <li>
                    <a href=
                    "http://www.jonhowlett.uk/home_page.html">JH</a>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href=
                    "#">About<span class="caret"></span></a>

                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Biography</a>
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <a href=
                            "http://www.jonhowlett.uk/hobbies.html">Hobbies</a>
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <a href=
                            "http://www.jonhowlett.uk/resume.html">Work
                            History</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="#">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
<div id="removepadding">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <!--style as .container .jumbotron-->

            <h1>Jon Howlett</h1><!--style as .jumbotron .container h1-->

            <p>Aspiring web designer and front-end developer</p>
            <!--style as .jumbotron .container p-->
        </div>
    </div><!--container-fluid-->
</div><!--remove padding-->

<div id="summary-row">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4"><img src="images/placeholder.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="placeholder">
        <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4"><img src="images/placeholder.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="placeholder">
        <p></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4"><img src="images/placeholder.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="placeholder">
        <p></p>
    </div>  
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="homepage_footer">  
  <footer>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <ul class="nav nav pills" id="menu-footer-navigation">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Twitter</a>
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Facebook</a>
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <a href="#">LinkedIn</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="rightside">
                    <div id="telephone">
                        07557 302 517
                    </div>
                    <div id="email">
                        jon@jonhowlett.uk
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
</div>
</div>`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ID > `#summary-row { height: 500px; }` is the issue with the footer being covered by another DIV but there are other areas you should look at that are causing structural problems, primarily when the viewport is reduced.

Your content is cut off on the right side of the browser due to this rule in `custom_new.css`: `.container .row { width: 1140px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; }`. Overriding rules is perfectly fine but it's important to apply them to either fine grained instances so they won't alter your entire layout/other parts that use the same default rule(s) or make sure the changes will work globally. (**You also have an extra closing bracket `;` at the end of your first Jumbtron rule**).

If you want a Jumbotron to be fillwidth, put a `container` div inside the `jumbotron` div See Docs [Bootstrap 3 Jumbotron](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#jumbotron).

You have numerous classes/IDs (particularly for the footer) which seem redundant and could be reduced or combined.

It should be `.nav-pills`, not `.nav .pills` (at least as far as Bootstrap goes, see the Docs [Bootstrap 3 NAVs](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav).

There are obviously many pitfalls with anything new, these points are merely for awareness.

See sample Snippet example below.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Allerta+Stencil%7CAbel%7CRoboto%7CPacifico');
 html {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
html,
body {
  overflow-y: none;
  height: 100%;
  margin-top: 130px;
}
.navbar.navbar-default {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 35px;
  border-bottom: 10px solid #F2F2F2;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav.navbar-right > li > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav.navbar-right .dropdown-menu > li > a {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Abel', Arial;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: black;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav.navbar-left > li > a {
  font-family: 'Allerta Stencil', arial;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: black;
}
.jumbotron {
  background-image: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e6/Los_Angeles_-_Echangeur_autoroute_110_105.JPG');
  width: 100%;
  height: 580px;
  border-bottom: 10px solid #F2F2F2;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}
.jumbotron .container h1 {
  font-family: 'Allerta Stencil', arial;
  font-size: 100px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-top: 70px;
  color: #fff;
}
.jumbotron .container p {
  font-family: 'Pacifico', arial;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 60px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  color: #fff;
}
#summary-row p {
  padding-top: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}
#summary-row img:hover {
  filter: brightness(70%);
  -webkit-filter: brightness(70%);
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
}
footer {
  font-family: 'Abel', Arial;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 175px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  padding: 30px 5px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #404241;
  color: white;
}
footer a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
footer ul.nav.nav-pills > li {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: left;
}
footer ul.nav.nav-pills > li > a:hover,
footer ul.nav.nav-pills > li > a:focus {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 0;
}
footer .rightside {
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: right;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .jumbotron {
    height: 380px;
  }
  .jumbotron .container h1 {
    font-size: 50px;
    margin-top: 30px;
  }
  .jumbotron .container p {
    font-size: 30px;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }
  footer .rightside {
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-size: 15px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button class="navbar-toggle" data-target=".navbar-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" type="button"><span class="icon-bar"></span>  <span class="icon-bar"></span>  <span class="icon-bar"></span>

      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
        <li> <a href="http://www.jonhowlett.uk/home_page.html">JH</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="dropdown"> <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">About<span class="caret"></span></a>

          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li> <a href="#">Biography</a>

            </li>
            <li> <a href="http://www.jonhowlett.uk/hobbies.html">Hobbies</a>

            </li>
            <li> <a href="http://www.jonhowlett.uk/resume.html">Work
                            History</a>

            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li> <a href="#">Portfolio</a>

        </li>
        <li> <a href="#">Contact</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container">
    <!--style as .container .jumbotron-->
    <h1>Jon Howlett</h1>

    <!--style as .jumbotron .container h1-->
    <p>Aspiring web designer and front-end developer</p>
    <!--style as .jumbotron .container p-->
  </div>
</div>
<!--remove padding-->
<div class="container">
  <div class="row" id="summary-row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <img src="https://www.airshare.co.nz/sites/default/files/NZ_0.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="placeholder">
      <p>ultrices mollis pulvinar enim, in diam. Cras posuere justo tempor pretium vitae, urna consectetuer amet ultricies diam morbi provident, quos ut ipsum, tempus fusce, eget nullam condimentum suscipit suspendisse. Semper nulla at, leo ut, sed metus
        nunc eros a, et sapien nisl wisi magna dolor, sit lorem hymenaeos. Orci morbi</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <img src="https://www.airshare.co.nz/sites/default/files/NZ_0.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="placeholder">
      <p>ultrices mollis pulvinar enim, in diam. Cras posuere justo tempor pretium vitae, urna consectetuer amet ultricies diam morbi provident, quos ut ipsum, tempus fusce, eget nullam condimentum suscipit suspendisse. Semper nulla at, leo ut, sed metus
        nunc eros a, et sapien nisl wisi magna dolor, sit lorem hymenaeos. Orci morbi</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <img src="https://www.airshare.co.nz/sites/default/files/NZ_0.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="placeholder">
      <p>ultrices mollis pulvinar enim, in diam. Cras posuere justo tempor pretium vitae, urna consectetuer amet ultricies diam morbi provident, quos ut ipsum, tempus fusce, eget nullam condimentum suscipit suspendisse. Semper nulla at, leo ut, sed metus
        nunc eros a, et sapien nisl wisi magna dolor, sit lorem hymenaeos. Orci morbi</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<footer>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills">
          <li> <a href="#">Twitter</a>

          </li>
          <li> <a href="#">Facebook</a>

          </li>
          <li> <a href="#">LinkedIn</a>

          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div class="rightside">
          <div id="telephone">07557 302 517</div>
          <div id="email">jon@jonhowlett.uk</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with help of [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries). For example, for display less than 990px you need to write this style sheet:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 990px) {
    // Your CSS here
}
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/14pn6bcv) is demo example.

```css
h1 {
    color: red;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 990px) {
    h1 {
        color: green;    
    }
}
```

```html
<h1>Hello world</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should take this CSS class off:

```
#summary-row {
    height: 500px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is not necessary remove **height:500px of summary-row** or adjust it for smaller screen when the width of device changes (In your case when you resize your browser)